# Word for a zig-zag polygonal line

Tags: word-choice, mathematics, shapes

We have to find an adjective to describe a family of abstract mathematical objects with a shape that (in an abstract setting) reminds of a diagonal polygonal line like the following.

[image]

The segments composing it can have arbitrary lengths, but are always at a 45° angle with the horizontal direction.

We first considered **zig-zag**, translating literally from our native language, but we were told by a colleague (also not a native English speaker) that it's not a common word at all in the US and would not be a good description. Also, most Google Image results for "zig-zag" return a regular pattern in which all segments have the same length, which is not our case.

Another suggestion was **twisted**.

What would be the most fitting term?

Comment: I'm a reasonable linguist and I taught mathematics to beyond A-Level. You can never prove a negative, but I'd say the probability of your finding a better term than _zig-zag_ is extremely low. // I'd check online to assess the reliability of your colleague's opinions. They don't match mine. And [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zigzag) labels the most obvious example 'a regular zigzag'.

Comment: ... The first non-regular example I saw in a Google image search, in [an article by Jeremy Wagner](https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/news/elliott-wave-patterns-zigzag-141100284.html), makes 'all Google Image results for "zig-zag" return a regular pattern in which all segments have the same length' rather suspect. / Dictionary definitions vary in the strengths of their suggestions of regularity for the bare term 'zigzag'. // Google Ngrams for _zig-zag_ and _zigzag_ for the relevant US corpora show little change from those based on the more general corpora.

Comment: I think *zigzag* is a perfectly good name for this object. It's common enough that everybody knows what it is; it's not already in use as a mathematical term; and its real meaning is close to the definition you want. Much better than *twisted*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks! I have made my statement about Google images results less absolute. You make very good points (especially checking Ngrams corpora is a great idea).

Comment: You could say 'crooked' but 'zig-zag' is better, in my opinion.

Comment: *Twisted* is completely wrong though. It doesn't fit the straight segments and would describe loops better. The only other word I could offer is *jagged* but I don't recommend it over zigzag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google image search for [“irregular zig-zag"](https://www.google.de/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enDE701DE701&hl=de&biw=1024&bih=653&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=mU94WqL7FIXbwQK0trso&q=%22irregular%20zig-zag%22&oq=%22irregular%20zig-zag%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-img.3..35i39k1.38090.41735.0.43136.10.10.0.0.0.0.585.3285.0j2j2j1j1j3.9.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-img..2.5.2150...0i7i30k1j0i7i5i30k1j0i8i7i30k1j30i10k1.172.RIbOCw-sWz8) gives results most consistent with your illustration, such as this one:

[image]

Comment: Good answer, but you have used "zig-zag" as a noun whereas OP asks for an adjective. I'd suggest editing in a dictionary entry (e.g. [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/zigzag?s=t)) which clarifies that it is also an adjective.

Comment: Actually, I merely googled for a collocation. "irregular zig-zag" could just as easily be two adjectives.

Comment: An irregularly zig-zagged line (with uniform angles).